# Serial invocation of JS functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, post

Here is what I am trying to do (The actual problem is different, but an overview of it is as follows):

1. I have an array [A..Z].
2. For each alphabet from the above array, I have another array as:

   ```
   someArray[alphabet] = [1..100] //another array
   ```
3. For each number in **someArray[alphabet]**, there is yet another array:

   ```
   anotherArray[number] = [a..z,A..Z,1..1000]
   ```

Assume that for each **alphabet**, I fetch **someArray[alphabet]**, and for each **number** in **someArray[alphabet]**, I fetch **anotherArray[number]**, all from the server - **It takes time.**

Also, the functions to get them are as follows - I make **jQuery post** calls to get data from the server. I need to execute them in order.

```
getAlphabets()
{
    //I get them here
    //For Each alpha, I call:
    getNumbers(alpha);
}
getNumbers(alpha)
{
    //I get someArray here.
    //For Each element in someArray
    //getAnotherArray(element)
}
getAnotherArray(number)
{
    //I get them here
    //For Each element in anotherArray
    //get all [a..z,A..Z,1..1000]
    //display them
}
```

The problem is an iteration of **getNumbers(alpha)** does not wait for the **getAnotherArray(previousIteration)** to complete. The executions (function invocations run in parallel (simultaneous executions for A..Z) and not otherwise.

My steps:

1. I am able to retrieve all data as expected, but not sequentially.
2. I tried using **flags** and **setInterval, clearInterval** to allow/disallow next iterations - They do not work as expected.
3. I also tried using something like - **getAlphabets() && getNumbers() & getAnotherArray()**, thinking that that would execute sequentially, but I was wrong.

Comment: Do you have to do a separate ajax call for every single cell in your 3D array and you want those to run sequentially?  Do these arrays already exist and you just want to iterate through them making an ajax call for each cell?  Or are you building the arrays as you make ajax calls?

Comment: I am building the arrays using ajax calls. First I get the list of alphabets. Then, for each alphabet, I invoke getNumbers(), and for each number in the array returned by getNumbers(), I invoke getAnotherArray() -> It passes appropriate parameters, gets the respective elements and builds an array out of that. I am able to do them all at once, but I need them to be sequential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate through some data structure sequentially when you have an async operation like an ajax call, you have to use a different form of iteration.  You can't use the regular `for` loop or `while` loop.  Instead, you create a function for doing an iteration.  You create a state variable that keeps track of where you are in the iteration.  You launch an Ajax call.  When it returns, you process the result and then launch the next ajax call (updating the iteration state as you go).

Here's an example:

Let's suppose you have an array of arbitrary length:

```
var theData = [...];
```

And, you want to make an ajax call for each item in that array and collect the results into another array.  For a particular reason, you want to force the Ajax calls to be sequential so that the 2nd call is only made after the 1st call has completed and so on.

```
function processArray(data) {
    var def = $.Deferred();
    var currentItem = 0;
    var results = [];

    function next() {
        if (currentItem < data.length) {
            $.ajax(...).done(function(result) {
                // process the result here
                results.push(result);
                // advance the counter and start the next Ajax call
                ++currentItem;
                next();
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                def.reject(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            });
        } else {
             def.resolve(results);
        }
    }
    next();
    return def.promise();
}

// call it like this
processArray(theData).done(function(results) {
    // do something with the results array here
});
```

Now, if you have three dimensions of iteration state, then keeping track of the state gets a little more complicated (you would have three versions of currentItem to keep track of where you are in each of the three dimensions), but it could otherwise be similar logic with the added complication of when you finish one dimension, you need to wrap to the next row and start again.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Please give me some time to understand the code.

Answer (score -1):

When you are doing ajax to fetch the data, the request are not executed in sequental manner as ajax is a async function. You need to turn th `async` off. So, that it will run in the sequential order as you want it.

```
async: false
```

**async (default: true)**
*Type: Boolean*
By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.

**Example :**

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: strUrl,
    success: function(html) {
      strReturn = html;
    },
    async:false
  });
```

Comment: It is NEVER a good idea to use `async: false` with ajax calls as it just locks up the browser.  The solution is to code the iteration a different way that works with async calls, not to get rid of the async calls.